# Should we create questions with answers regarding current issues that may be temporary?

Tags: discussion

This came up only because of the current issues with CLI and rest deployments, noted [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/942).

Recently, we got a [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/337692/a-simple-try-for-deploying-gets-an-an-internal-server-error-from-the-productio#comment497791_337692) that was appropriately closed as it really had no information other than an error id.

However, it does seem really common right now that if you're sporadically running into deployment issues with VS Code that setting the following flag would be a temporary workaround until the rest deploy is bug-free.

`sfdx config:set restDeploy=false`

This "workaround" would be (hopefully) temporary. Is it worth putting in a question and answer to reference this in general - almost similar to the issue they created in the github repo?

The only thing we have to go on is that if someone is putting a question about getting an error-id sometimes when deploying (or just deploying issues in general) then it's most likely this issue right now (or at least a good first step). We may also need to know the specific CLI version as eventually the answer will just be "upgrade the CLI".

My only concern is that when this is "over", the question and answer may no longer really be relevant or we'd need to update it to specifically mention the issue only occurred on certain CLI versions.

The other option would be to get this information to an already existing community answer that covers this. This was the [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/161713/internal-server-error-what-now) used to close the question, but this doesn't seem like it fits what it was going for which was to explain what a gack is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the answer is a community wiki page similar to canonical-qa that @davidreed initiated. a `Does this answer your question <link>` response to these temporal SFDX questions.

That is, common SFDX issues and their solutions/workarounds could be kept (and updated) as evergreen answers